# input too large for RSA cipher - I need a working, in-memory alternative to openssl cms decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl

I have the following openssl command which works perfectly fine to decrypt a .mp3.bin encrypted file with an RSA private key I have:

```
openssl.exe cms -decrypt -inform DER -in {inFilePath} -binary -inkey {privateKey} -out {outFilePath}
```

The issue I'm having is that this only seems to work with files which I already have on my local machine. I am looking for a way to do this same decryption but in memory, i want to decrypt a file in the cloud in my programs memory and then write the decrypted stream which is in memory to another location in the cloud. The above command seems to only work with local files which can be found in a local drive.

I've looked into bouncy castle and other options but I have not found anything that works. I have this code but it returns an error: "Unhandled Exception: Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher." For now, I am just testing decrypting a file in memory which is already on my local machine.

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = getPrivateKey(privateKeyFileName);
RsaEngine e = new RsaEngine();
e.Init(false, privateKey);
byte[] decryptedAudioFile = File.ReadAllBytes(binFileName);
byte[] decrypted = e.ProcessBlock(decryptedAudioFile, 0, decryptedAudioFile.Length);

static AsymmetricKeyParameter getPrivateKey(string privateKeyFileName)
        {
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;
            using(var reader = File.OpenText(privateKeyFileName))
            {
                keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
            }
            return keyPair.Private;
        }
```

I am not really sure why the error is stating the input is too large for the RSA key since it works with the previously mentioned openssl cms command, can someone please help? Let me know if anything is unclear please!

Comment: What is the RSA key size and the encrypted file size?

Comment: The length of the byte array holding the audio file which is encrypted in .bin format = 6357664
The number of characters in my RSA private key = 1592

Comment: The type in .NET is System.Security.Cryptography.EnvelopedCms. It’s in System.Security.dll (.NET Framework) or System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs via NuGet (.NET Core or Framework).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the CMS libraries of Bouncy Castle to do that kind of decryption. The RSA used in CMS is not just RSA, it is RSA + AES, in a container structure. Search for `CmsEnvelopedDataParser` to get more information.

Note that CMS is also directly supported by the Microsoft API, search in this case for `EnvelopedCms`.

Currently you are directly using RSA, which is indeed not directly usable - and definitely not practical - for larger amounts of data.

---

It's a bit much for me to setup Bouncy C#, but probably if I give you the source in Java then you should be able to use largely the same classes in C#. The biggest trick is the key / `Receipient` handling possibly.

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * openssl genrsa -out rsaprivkey.pem 2048
 * openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in rsaprivkey.pem -out privkey.pem 
 * openssl req -x509 -key privkey.pem -out encrypt.cer 
 * openssl cms -encrypt -binary -in plain.txt -outform DER -out enveloped.p7 encrypt.cer
 * openssl cms -decrypt -binary -inform DER -in enveloped.p7 -out decrypted_openssl.txt -inkey privkey.pem
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @author maartenb
 */
public class DecryptRSACms {

    private static void decrypt(PrivateKey privateKey, File encrypted, File decryptedDestination)
            throws IOException, CMSException {
        byte[] encryptedData = Files.readAllBytes(encrypted.toPath());

        CMSEnvelopedDataParser parser = new CMSEnvelopedDataParser(encryptedData);

        RecipientInformation recInfo = getSingleRecipient(parser);
        Recipient recipient = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(privateKey);

        try (InputStream decryptedStream = recInfo.getContentStream(recipient).getContentStream()) {
            Files.copy(decryptedStream, decryptedDestination.toPath());
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Decrypted '%s' to '%s'", encrypted.getAbsolutePath(),
                decryptedDestination.getAbsolutePath()));
    }

    private static RecipientInformation getSingleRecipient(CMSEnvelopedDataParser parser) {
        Collection<RecipientInformation> recInfos = parser.getRecipientInfos().getRecipients();
        Iterator<RecipientInformation> recipientIterator = recInfos.iterator();
        if (!recipientIterator.hasNext()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find recipient");
        }
        return (RecipientInformation) recipientIterator.next();
    }

    private static RSAPrivateKey parsePrivateKey(File privateKeyPEM) throws IOException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        PemObject readPemObject;
        try (PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(privateKeyPEM))) {
            readPemObject = parser.readPemObject();
        }
        System.out.println(readPemObject.getType());
        byte[] pkcs8KeyData = readPemObject.getContent();
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8KeyData);
        KeyFactory kf;
        try {
            kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
        return (RSAPrivateKey) privKey;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = parsePrivateKey(new File(args[0]));
        decrypt(rsaPrivateKey, new File(args[1]), new File(args[2]));
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like the PKCS class from Microsoft is not working, I cannot import it from:
using System.Security.Cryptography(.Pkcs doesn't resolve);
Also I'm struggling to find an example of the Bouncy Castle implementation..

Comment: Added Java example, sorry, I would have to do a lot to get my C# env running again. Feel free to replace with C# code.